# WPF: ListView SelectedItem binding works for a split second, then changes back

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

let me start by introducing my current setup:
I have a ListView that binds its SelectedItem property to the ViewModel, like this:

```
    <ListView Name="FileListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" 
              SelectionChanged="ImageSelectionChanged"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <view:FileListItem />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

It's item template (view:FileListItem) is the following:

```
<Grid MouseDown="FileListItemMouseDown" KeyDown="FileListItemKeyDown">
    ....
    <TextBlock Name="NewNameTextBlock" 
             Text="{Binding NewName}" 
             Grid.Column="2"
             Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibility}" />

    <TextBox Name="NewNameTextBox" 
             Text="{Binding NewName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             Grid.Column="2"
             Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisibility}" />
</Grid>
```

The idea here is to switch on the TextBox and switch off the TextBlock when the corresponding ListView item is being edited. This works ok, but when I hit a particular key, I want the ListView to select the next item and put that item into editing mode. I catch the KeyDown event as seen above in the ItemTemplate and broadcast a message, which is caught in the DataContext of my ListView like this:

```
    public ImageFile SelectedItem {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { _selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
    }

    public void SelectAndEditThisHandler (object x)
    {
        ImageFile file = x as ImageFile;
        SelectedItem = file;
    }
```

The result is that the selection actually changes for a split second, but then it changes back to the previous selection. I suspect some other UI elements might be handling my key-presses and doing something to change the selection back, but I can't figure out which elements and how to pinpoint them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
As requested, the SelectionChanged handler:

```
    private void ImageSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.IList filelist = FileListView.SelectedItems;
        if (filelist.Count == 1)
        {
            ImageFile selectedFile = FileListView.SelectedItem as ImageFile;
            Mediator.Instance.NotifyColleagues(Mediator.Operations.ImagePathSelected, selectedFile.OriginalPath);
        }
    }
```

The mediator message broadcast doesn't do anything related to these controls/this problem at all.

Comment: Try handling the KeyUP not KeyDown.  OK I get you may need to handle the KeyDown but do it to see if it changes the selection behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it with KeyUp, but the behavior remains exactly the same. It might be worth noting that the ListViewItem that wrongly ends up being selected also has a dashed bounding box around it.

Comment: Post the selectionchanged event handler

Comment: Ok, Added the SelectionChanged handler to the main post..

Comment: Stupid question, have you tried marking the keydown event as handled in your custom handler?

Comment: Yup, that is the first thing I did :)